# How to Generate 3x3 HTML Table From an JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-table

I have an array of values in Javascript as follows:

```
var data = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I" };
```

How can I generate a 3x3 HTML table like the following

```
A    B    C

D    E    F

G    H    I
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: That's not even valid JavaScript...

Comment: var data = {...} <= object ...var data = [...] <= array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I" ]; // corrected Array syntax

var table = document.createElement("table");
var i = 0;
for (var r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  for (var c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
    var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
    cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i++]));
  }
}

document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Comment: +1 for using DOM `createElement`, and `createTextNode`. I've seen many programmers take the shortcut using a string and innerHTML. Personally I prefer your approach.

Comment: I have this same issue, except 4 columns and undefined number of rows.  I like that your answer doesn't use innerHtml, however I can't seem to get it to work. Even when I plug yours into jsfiddle.net nothing shows up. Does the html body need to have a table set up?

Comment: Yep, I forgot the argument for `insertRow` and `insertCell`. It works now: http://jsfiddle.net/ekaw7/ For your requirements, replace the outer `for` loop with a `while` loop, that checks if data is still available, and an additional check before using the data. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ekaw7/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I" ];
var html = '<table><tr>';
for(var i = 0 ; i<data.length; i++){
    if(i%3 == 0 && i != 0){
       html+= '</tr><tr>'
    }
    html+='<td>'+data[i]+'</td>';
}
html+='</tr></table>';

document.write(html);
```

Comment: that'll leave you an empty row up top

Comment: That's the same answer I posted, but you were first.. :)

Comment: @jswolf91 nope, coz there's the check i!=0 that avoid the empty row ;)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/DuSP5/ just tried this one.